# Редуцированный гласный в слове «помогать»

Tags: фонетика

Здравствуйте. Возник вопрос: в слове *помогать* после М слышится звук, который больше похож на [а], а не на [о], так ли это? Правильно ли называть в таком случае этот звук редуцированным? Согласно правилу, редукция — это изменение произношения гласных звуков, находящихся в слабой позиции. Заранее благодарю за ответ, и не нужно меня ругать за такой, возможно, простой вопрос. :)

P.S. Ещё хотелось бы узнать, как показать этот звук в фонетической транскрипции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Редукция - это качественное и количественное изменение гласных в безударных слогах (слабая позиция).

Гласные А и О после твердых согласных произносятся как звук, похожий на А, но более краткий, он обозначается как Λ (1-я степень редукции) или как  Ъ - вторая степень редукции (очень короткий звук).

В слове "помогать" в первом предударном слоге происходит редукция 2-й степени, а во втором - редукция 1-й степени: [пъмΛгат']

Answer (score 0):

Да, в этом слове действительно 2 редукционных звука. Если вы учитесь в школе, то транскрипция слова будет выглядеть так:(памагат'), если это высшее учебное заведение, то транскрипция будет выглядеть так: (пъмΛгат'). Только в квадратных скобках.